# Why Testcafe ignoring the first condition of If Else If statement

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, assertion, testcafe

I have the following security questions in my application

1. What was your first phone number?
2. What is your favorite color?
3. Who is your favorite sports team?

Below is the part of the code

```
export default class webPage {
constructor () {
this.securityQuestion = Selector('#challengeQuestionLabelId');
this.sportQuestion    = this.securityQuestion.withText('sports');
this.colorQuestion    = this.securityQuestion.withText('color');
this.phoneQuestion    = this.securityQuestion.withText('phone');

}
}
```

Conditional statements

```
async answerSecurityQuestion() { 
                 var myAnswer; 

                 if ( await this.webPage.colorQuestion.exists ) { 
                     myAnswer = "color1"; 
                 } else if ( await this.webPage.phoneQuestion.exists ) { 
                     myAnswer = "phone1"; 
                 } else {
                     myAnswer = "sports1"; 
                 }
```

The issue is with the first if statement.Code is not identifying first if the question even if the question contains "color".

I have switched the order of statement and found the issue is not with the selectors but the issue is with the first if statement.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: I created a test with a similar scenario, but my attempts to replicate this behavior were unsuccessful. Would you please clarify to what you are referring by keyword 'this'? What do you mean by 'issue is with the first if statement'? Is there any error message when the first statement is executed?

Answer (score 2):

Adding below await statement solved the issue.

```
await t.wait(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a couple of parenthesis:

```
async answerSecurityQuestion() { 

             var myAnswer; 

             if ( (await this.webPage.colorQuestion).exists ) { 
                 myAnswer = "color1"; 
             } else if ( (await this.webPage.phoneQuestion).exists ) { 
                 myAnswer = "phone1"; 
             } else {
                 myAnswer = "sports1"; 
             }

}
```

That is, you await the thing in parenthesis, right?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It stopped working after applying the parenthesis as suggested. So, I think we await the entire function/condition.